# s3のファイルアップロードしてlambdaを発火させる際にprefixを動的な値にすることはできますか？

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

### やりたいこと

1. 特定のs3のprefixでファイルがアップロードされたときだけlambda関数を実行させたいです。
2. prefixを動的な値で送りたい。
   例を出すとs3のprefix設定でtest/{dynamic-id}/photo-id/にした場合、test/1/photo-idや
   test/2/photo-idでファイルをアップロードしたら、
   lambdaが発火されるが、test/3/sample/でアップロードすると発火されないようにしたい。

### 問題点

lambdaにs3をアタッチさせた状態で設定のトリガーからs3のprefixをtest/{dynamic-id}/photo-id/にして
s3のバケットのtest/1/photo-idでファイルをアップロードしたのですが、現状lambda関数が発火されておりません。
トリガー設定のprefixをtest/にした状態でtest/1/photo-idでファイルをアップロードすると発火します。
ただこれだとtest/2/photo-idでもlambdaが発火されてしまいます。
何かアドバイスあればお願いします。

Comment: ただこれだと～の部分が何を言いたいのかイマイチよくわからないのですが、なにがどういう場合に発火するのがどう問題なのか、わかるように編集いただけますか？

Comment: 「prefixを動的な値」が何を言っているのかわかりませんでした。その動的な値はいつ決まるのでしょうか？ S3にアップロードされてから判断するのであれば、lambdaで判断するコードを記述すればいいのでは？

Comment: @sayuri lambdaで判定して指定したprefix以外であれば処理をしないようにもできますが、発火自体は行われてしまいます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文が整理されておらず読み取りづらいのですが、要するに

- 発火してほしいパターン

  - `test/1/photo-id`
  - `test/2/photo-id`
- 発火してほしくないパターン

  - `test/3/sample/` （なぜ `/` で終わるのか不明。質問文の誤りか？）

でしょうか？

そうであれば、

- プレフィックス `test/`
- サフィックス `/photo-id`

と設定するだけではないでしょうか。

Comment: おしゃっていただいたアドバイスをもとに該当画像に「画像名_original.png」として保存してs3のsuffix設定を_original.pngにしたら意図通りの挙動を実現できました。
ありがとうございます。